# Why Openshift 4.X only support 3 masters

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I made a OKD 4.9 cluster.

I successfully installed openshift and made a cluster, but I got a question now.

There is a sentence in OKD document.

"The only supported values is 3, which is the default value"

I think there is an important reason to do not use 5, 7 masters.

Could you guys tell me why?

Comment: can you paste the link to the document?

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_container_platform/4.9/html/installing/installing-on-aws#installation-about-restricted-networks_installing-restricted-networks-aws-installer-provisioned

Here you are.

Answer (score 1):

> I think there is an important reason to do not use 5, 7 masters.
>
> Could you guys tell me why?

Technically it is still possible to have 5 or 7 Master Nodes, there is nothing in place to stop you. It is just not supported, so if you have a problem with it you'll have to deal with it yourself.

However, you should understand why this recommendation is there. Many Kubernetes Master components (**Controller Manager**, **Scheduler**) are only active on one single Master Node anyway, while the same component on all other Masters are not active. **API Server** is active-active, so API Server scales nicely.

For **etcd**, Raft is leader-based; the leader handles all client requests which need cluster consensus. Any request that requires consensus sent to a follower is automatically forwarded to the leader. So for write operations or for consistent reads, there is an overhead if you have more than 3 etcd members. If you have more etcd members, this overhead gets larger, but YMMV.

So it comes down to additional *overhead* with 5 or 7 Master Nodes.

Comment: So, the overheads from the number of etcds is problem. 
I think I should learn more about K8S.... I appreciate for your help.